# OAuth2 with CAS 6.1.4: is a client secret needed for PKCE authorization_code grant type?

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas, pkce

I'm trying to use the OAuth2 features of CAS 6.1.4, and specifically the Proof Key Code Exchange (PKCE) variant of the *authorization_code* grant type: I set everything up and *authorization_code* works both in its basic form and PKCE variant.

However, it seems like a *client_secret* request parameter **must** be provided even when using the PKCE variant – I haven't found a way to avoid that. That seems counterintuitive, as PKCE was introduced for public clients that cannot hold a client secret safely. The [RCF 7636 specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) and the [documentation on the Apereo site](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html#proof-key-code-exchange-pkce) are silent about whether the *authorization_code* request should be authenticated by the client secret.

Please tell me if I'm missing out on something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question here, just in case someone stumbles upon the question.

As it turns out, you can define *public clients* in CAS by simply omitting the `clientSecret` field of the corresponding CAS service. (See for [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.1.x/installation/OAuth-OpenId-Authentication.html#register-clients) for a full description of the OAuth2 client definition, as of CAS 6.1.x.).
A public client does not require the `client_secret` request parameter and one can exercise the *authorization_code* grant type without providing that parameter, PKCE variant or not.

Not that this is written anywhere, I found out by good old trial and error.

Comment: WOW. Thanks a lot, I was close to give up on that matter